# Is it possible to read the excel cell value with formula?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

In my following code, the value of c4 is coming out zero. C4 cell has formula SUM(C2:C3). 
Is EPPlus capable of reading cell with formula? Why is c4 being set to zero instead of 12.

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
    var currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();

    currentWorksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 5;
    currentWorksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 7;
    var c4 = Convert.ToDouble(currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Value); //c4 is zero. why?
}
```

Comment: Can you try `.Formula` instead of `.Value`? This could help.

Comment: currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Formula returns "SUM(C2:C3)"

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did not read your question carefully enough. The problem here is that the calculations cannot be performed via EPPlus. Excel needs to calculate the formula and as far as I understood the file needs to be opened therefore.

Answer (score 13):

As of EpPlus 4.0.1.1, there is an extension method `public static void Calculate(this ExcelRangeBase range)`. Invoke it prior to accessing C4's Value property:

```
currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Calculate();
```

and `currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Value` will return `12` after that.

Comment: I could kiss you for this answer. It took me 5 hours to find this.