# C# EPPlus get value of formula cell

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, epplus

I have a simple formula in a number of cells and I'm trying to get the result of that formula into a variable in my program. My inital code was:
`var ECC = ws.Cells["B14"].Value;
decimal ECP = Convert.ToDecimal(ECC);`
but this got me an error "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelErrorValue' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'"
I tried calculating and adding a toString, making my code:
`ws.Cells["B14"].Calculate();
decimal ECP = Convert.ToDecimal(ws.Cells["B14"].Value.ToString());`
This got me a different error: "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" on the second line.

The result of the formula will always be a decimal and it's important that I get it into a decimal variable because I'm putting that value into a SQL database. How can I do this error-free?

Comment: Looks like your formula is not properly formatted

Comment: My formula is formatted correctly; the code later opens the Excel sheet and that cell has the correct formula & value

Answer (score 0):

This works in one my apps:

```
var pressure = informationWorkSheet.Cells[30, 3];
```

Cast it to a Decimal:

```
Decimal pressureDecimal = (Decimal) pressure;
```

Or parse it:

```
Decimal.Parse(pressure.ToString());
```

Comment: I changed it to a lowercase decimal because it got upset with "Decimal". Casting a cell to a decimal doesn't work; I tried getting the value of the cell and casting that to a decimal. It told me the specified cast isn't valid. I then tried parsing it and I'm back to "Input string was not in a correct format".

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach with `decimal.TryParse`. Works as expected in my sample application.
Tested with values: 3,2 / 3.2 / 5

```
string ECC = ws.Cells["B14"].Value.ToString();
bool isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(ECC, out decimal result);
if (isDecimal)
{
    decimal ECP = result;
}
```

Comment: I just tried putting this in and unfortunately it isn't working for me. Whether I calculate cell B14 or not, ECC is still "#VALUE!" and isDecimal is false.

Comment: Are you trying to read a formula in the Excel sheet? Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213106/is-it-possible-to-read-the-excel-cell-value-with-formula) can help you out?